# Scrollable Y axis on DIV overflowing outer container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a box that has two columns. The left column should have a heading and scrollable content. When I add a heading to the left column, it pushes the next element down. How can I have it so that it is flush with the container?

Check out the [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/43x9tdrr/) I made as it is easy to see the issue.

**CSS**

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
#container{
    width:100%;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 400px;
    padding: 5px;
}
#col1{
    width: 33.33%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
   float:left;
}
#col2{
    float:left;
    width: 66.66%;
    background-color: yellow;
    height:100%;
}
#scrollplease{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with it is flush with the container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


.Main {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}


.Aside {
  width: 200px; /* Any size */
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  background: #02c39a; /* For demo */
}

.Aside__header {
  height: 120px; /* Any size */
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.2); /* For demo */
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.Aside__content {
  flex: 1;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.2); /* For demo */
  overflow-y: auto;
}


.Section {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  background: #f0f3bd; /* For demo */
}

.Section__header {
  height: 120px; /* Any size */
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.Section__content {
  flex: 1;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.2); /* For demo */
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<main class="Main">
  <aside class="Aside">
    <header class="Aside__header">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut tincidunt augue et justo condimentum sollicitudin. Quisque eget justo enim. Duis faucibus enim vitae gravida aliquet. Cras rutrum laoreet felis, vel pellentesque dolor auctor varius. Fusce laoreet eu diam sit amet varius. Pellentesque mollis vehicula tempus. Maecenas iaculis, mi quis tincidunt auctor, nulla neque fermentum dolor, id finibus neque nulla et sem. Curabitur pretium neque ut lacus faucibus mollis. Aenean sed leo laoreet, suscipit ante nec, varius erat. Nulla varius rutrum mauris, nec semper libero egestas et. Fusce laoreet rutrum turpis sit amet ultricies. Nulla porttitor iaculis consectetur. Vivamus ultrices ornare eros vel rutrum. Nam ut pellentesque tortor. Morbi quis varius ligula. Praesent semper non massa nec lobortis. Phasellus faucibus blandit porttitor. Etiam sagittis ut tellus a tristique. Fusce dolor ex, laoreet non lectus in, dignissim ultricies tellus. Donec a nulla ac lorem ultrices ullamcorper sed id ante. Suspendisse efficitur posuere mattis. Nullam faucibus hendrerit laoreet. Ut malesuada suscipit lacus vitae blandit. Donec lobortis, sapien in bibendum molestie, orci tortor cursus urna, rutrum varius dui neque a arcu. Pellentesque a fermentum massa. Vestibulum id lectus vel massa vulputate pulvinar. Nulla ante ligula, aliquet sed condimentum at, euismod vel risus. Vivamus vitae aliquam ligula. Nullam dignissim vel felis eu dapibus. Cras at scelerisque lectus. Praesent eleifend sed diam sed gravida. Cras quis volutpat nisl, ut ullamcorper sem. Vivamus viverra mollis est, quis consequat elit porta sit amet. Proin quis accumsan leo. Phasellus neque dui, ullamcorper non magna non, vulputate vulputate nisi. Integer luctus sem sapien, at ultricies tellus aliquam tincidunt. Vivamus faucibus gravida dui, at efficitur nisi commodo eu. Suspendisse volutpat orci eget elit porttitor, sed pulvinar nibh fringilla. Maecenas risus elit, gravida id sem nec, bibendum mattis ante. Sed eleifend mollis iaculis. Cras tempor tellus eget luctus fringilla. Pellentesque vehicula purus ipsum, vitae condimentum dui suscipit vitae. Quisque blandit accumsan nunc non rhoncus. Duis faucibus imperdiet eleifend.</header>
    <div class="Aside__content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut tincidunt augue et justo condimentum sollicitudin. Quisque eget justo enim. Duis faucibus enim vitae gravida aliquet. Cras rutrum laoreet felis, vel pellentesque dolor auctor varius. Fusce laoreet eu diam sit amet varius. Pellentesque mollis vehicula tempus. Maecenas iaculis, mi quis tincidunt auctor, nulla neque fermentum dolor, id finibus neque nulla et sem. Curabitur pretium neque ut lacus faucibus mollis. Aenean sed leo laoreet, suscipit ante nec, varius erat. Nulla varius rutrum mauris, nec semper libero egestas et. Fusce laoreet rutrum turpis sit amet ultricies. Nulla porttitor iaculis consectetur. Vivamus ultrices ornare eros vel rutrum. Nam ut pellentesque tortor. Morbi quis varius ligula. Praesent semper non massa nec lobortis. Phasellus faucibus blandit porttitor. Etiam sagittis ut tellus a tristique. Fusce dolor ex, laoreet non lectus in, dignissim ultricies tellus. Donec a nulla ac lorem ultrices ullamcorper sed id ante. Suspendisse efficitur posuere mattis. Nullam faucibus hendrerit laoreet. Ut malesuada suscipit lacus vitae blandit. Donec lobortis, sapien in bibendum molestie, orci tortor cursus urna, rutrum varius dui neque a arcu. Pellentesque a fermentum massa. Vestibulum id lectus vel massa vulputate pulvinar. Nulla ante ligula, aliquet sed condimentum at, euismod vel risus. Vivamus vitae aliquam ligula. Nullam dignissim vel felis eu dapibus. Cras at scelerisque lectus. Praesent eleifend sed diam sed gravida. Cras quis volutpat nisl, ut ullamcorper sem. Vivamus viverra mollis est, quis consequat elit porta sit amet. Proin quis accumsan leo. Phasellus neque dui, ullamcorper non magna non, vulputate vulputate nisi. Integer luctus sem sapien, at ultricies tellus aliquam tincidunt. Vivamus faucibus gravida dui, at efficitur nisi commodo eu. Suspendisse volutpat orci eget elit porttitor, sed pulvinar nibh fringilla. Maecenas risus elit, gravida id sem nec, bibendum mattis ante. Sed eleifend mollis iaculis. Cras tempor tellus eget luctus fringilla. Pellentesque vehicula purus ipsum, vitae condimentum dui suscipit vitae. Quisque blandit accumsan nunc non rhoncus. Duis faucibus imperdiet eleifend.</div>
  </aside>
  <section class="Section">
    <header class="Section__header">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut tincidunt augue et justo condimentum sollicitudin. Quisque eget justo enim. Duis faucibus enim vitae gravida aliquet. Cras rutrum laoreet felis, vel pellentesque dolor auctor varius. Fusce laoreet eu diam sit amet varius. Pellentesque mollis vehicula tempus. Maecenas iaculis, mi quis tincidunt auctor, nulla neque fermentum dolor, id finibus neque nulla et sem. Curabitur pretium neque ut lacus faucibus mollis. Aenean sed leo laoreet, suscipit ante nec, varius erat. Nulla varius rutrum mauris, nec semper libero egestas et. Fusce laoreet rutrum turpis sit amet ultricies. Nulla porttitor iaculis consectetur. Vivamus ultrices ornare eros vel rutrum. Nam ut pellentesque tortor. Morbi quis varius ligula. Praesent semper non massa nec lobortis. Phasellus faucibus blandit porttitor. Etiam sagittis ut tellus a tristique. Fusce dolor ex, laoreet non lectus in, dignissim ultricies tellus. Donec a nulla ac lorem ultrices ullamcorper sed id ante. Suspendisse efficitur posuere mattis. Nullam faucibus hendrerit laoreet. Ut malesuada suscipit lacus vitae blandit. Donec lobortis, sapien in bibendum molestie, orci tortor cursus urna, rutrum varius dui neque a arcu. Pellentesque a fermentum massa. Vestibulum id lectus vel massa vulputate pulvinar. Nulla ante ligula, aliquet sed condimentum at, euismod vel risus. Vivamus vitae aliquam ligula. Nullam dignissim vel felis eu dapibus. Cras at scelerisque lectus. Praesent eleifend sed diam sed gravida. Cras quis volutpat nisl, ut ullamcorper sem. Vivamus viverra mollis est, quis consequat elit porta sit amet. Proin quis accumsan leo. Phasellus neque dui, ullamcorper non magna non, vulputate vulputate nisi. Integer luctus sem sapien, at ultricies tellus aliquam tincidunt. Vivamus faucibus gravida dui, at efficitur nisi commodo eu. Suspendisse volutpat orci eget elit porttitor, sed pulvinar nibh fringilla. Maecenas risus elit, gravida id sem nec, bibendum mattis ante. Sed eleifend mollis iaculis. Cras tempor tellus eget luctus fringilla. Pellentesque vehicula purus ipsum, vitae condimentum dui suscipit vitae. Quisque blandit accumsan nunc non rhoncus. Duis faucibus imperdiet eleifend.</header>
    <div class="Section__content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut tincidunt augue et justo condimentum sollicitudin. Quisque eget justo enim. Duis faucibus enim vitae gravida aliquet. Cras rutrum laoreet felis, vel pellentesque dolor auctor varius. Fusce laoreet eu diam sit amet varius. Pellentesque mollis vehicula tempus. Maecenas iaculis, mi quis tincidunt auctor, nulla neque fermentum dolor, id finibus neque nulla et sem. Curabitur pretium neque ut lacus faucibus mollis. Aenean sed leo laoreet, suscipit ante nec, varius erat. Nulla varius rutrum mauris, nec semper libero egestas et. Fusce laoreet rutrum turpis sit amet ultricies. Nulla porttitor iaculis consectetur. Vivamus ultrices ornare eros vel rutrum. Nam ut pellentesque tortor. Morbi quis varius ligula. Praesent semper non massa nec lobortis. Phasellus faucibus blandit porttitor. Etiam sagittis ut tellus a tristique. Fusce dolor ex, laoreet non lectus in, dignissim ultricies tellus. Donec a nulla ac lorem ultrices ullamcorper sed id ante. Suspendisse efficitur posuere mattis. Nullam faucibus hendrerit laoreet. Ut malesuada suscipit lacus vitae blandit. Donec lobortis, sapien in bibendum molestie, orci tortor cursus urna, rutrum varius dui neque a arcu. Pellentesque a fermentum massa. Vestibulum id lectus vel massa vulputate pulvinar. Nulla ante ligula, aliquet sed condimentum at, euismod vel risus. Vivamus vitae aliquam ligula. Nullam dignissim vel felis eu dapibus. Cras at scelerisque lectus. Praesent eleifend sed diam sed gravida. Cras quis volutpat nisl, ut ullamcorper sem. Vivamus viverra mollis est, quis consequat elit porta sit amet. Proin quis accumsan leo. Phasellus neque dui, ullamcorper non magna non, vulputate vulputate nisi. Integer luctus sem sapien, at ultricies tellus aliquam tincidunt. Vivamus faucibus gravida dui, at efficitur nisi commodo eu. Suspendisse volutpat orci eget elit porttitor, sed pulvinar nibh fringilla. Maecenas risus elit, gravida id sem nec, bibendum mattis ante. Sed eleifend mollis iaculis. Cras tempor tellus eget luctus fringilla. Pellentesque vehicula purus ipsum, vitae condimentum dui suscipit vitae. Quisque blandit accumsan nunc non rhoncus. Duis faucibus imperdiet eleifend.</div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem may be with the height on `#scrollplease`. Try playing with the height. 80% seems like a good area to start with the demo.

```
#scrollplease{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 80%;
}
```

You may also want to play with the padding/margins on the `h2` and `ul` elements to get everything lined up.

Comment: This causes the scroll bar to go below the container.

Comment: Yep, you are right, thanks for pointing that out. Updating my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The user stylesheet or browser is adding margin to your h2 and ul.  you should be using a limited css reset at least.

You also need to counter the padding on the container with the heights and widths of the columns

I would do something like this:

```
h2 {
margin: 0;
}
ul {
margin: 0;
}
#container{
  width:100%;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  height: 400px;
}
#col1{
  width: 33%;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 1%;
  height: 380px;
  background-color: red;
  float:left;
}
.header{
  height: 15%;
}
#scrollplease{
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 85%;
}
#col2{
  float:left;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 1%;
  height: 380px;
  width: 65%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

See This [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/43x9tdrr/1/)

Comment: always keep in mind the [Box Model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp).  Your sizes, including padding, margins, and borders all make up the size of your div and heights can't really be responsive (at least, it's difficult in practice).

Answer (score 0):

The box height is set to 400px, and the scroll wrapper's height is set to 100% (which becomes 400px). Even if there is a header above the scroll box, taking up say ~75px, the height of the scroll wrapper stays at 400px, but starts lower, so extends outside the confines of the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do to avoid the list overflowing the container, is setting an `overflow:hidden` on the container class.

```js
$(".row-list").append("<p>World</p>");
$(".row-list").append("<p>World</p>");
$(".row-list").append("<p>World</p>");
$(".row-list").append("<p>World</p>");
$(".row-list").append("<p>World</p>");
$(".row-list").append("<p>World</p>");
$(".row-list").append("<p>World</p>");
$(".row-list").append("<p>World</p>");
$(".row-list").append("<p>World</p>");
$(".row-list").append("<p>World</p>");
$(".row-list").append("<p>World</p>");
$(".row-list").append("<p>World</p>");
$(".row-list").append("<p>World</p>");
$(".row-list").append("<p>World</p>");
$(".row-list").append("<p>World</p>");
$(".row-list").append("<p>World</p>");
$(".row-list").append("<p>World</p>");
$(".row-list").append("<p>World</p>");
$(".row-list").append("<p>World</p>");
$(".row-list").append("<p>World</p>");
$(".row-list").append("<p>World</p>");
$(".row-list").append("<p>World</p>");
$(".row-list").append("<p>World</p>");
$(".row-list").append("<p>World</p>");
```

```css
.container
{
  height:20em;
  width:20em;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.col
{
  height:100%;
  float:left;
}

.row
{
  height:3em;
  clear:both;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.row-list
{
  clear:both;
  height:calc(100% - 3em);
  overflow-y:auto;
}

.green
{
  background:green;
}

.blue
{
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="col green">
  <div class="row">
   <h1>Hello</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row-list">
   
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col blue">
  <div class="row">
   <h1>Hello</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <p>World</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```